# Bootstrap: Too Much Spacing (Not Responsive)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn bootstrap and built a website with a video background on top and text below it. **When I reduce the desktop size screen to one of mobile size, a large gap appears in between the video and body text.** Any help would be helpful in my pursuit to learn boostrap! Thanks so much.

[image: Picture of my problem]

I suspect it's a padding or margin problem? But why would it expand more when I make the browser window smaller?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class = "container-fluid">
        <div class = "row">

        <div class = "header-container">
            <div class = "video-container">
                <div align="center" class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                      // video code removed (for succinctness)
                </div> <!-- video responsiveness -->
            </div> <!-- video-container -->

            <div class = "col-md-12 text-center">
                <h3> 
                    TEXT
                </h3>
            </div>

            </div> <!-- header-container -->
            </div> <!-- row -->
        </div> <!-- container -->

    <section id="services">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-2" id="red">
                  <h2 class="text-center">
                  Services
                  </h2>

                  <p class="text-justify">
                    // BODY TEXT removed (for succinctness)
                  </p>
             </div>
```

CSS:

```
.header-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.video-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}

video { max-width: 100%; min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; }

#services{
    background-color: white;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not appear to be a padding or margin issue.

You have added some custom CSS **that specifies an explicit height** on your `header-container` class, i.e., `700px`.  At the same time, however, You are placing the video in a **responsive container** by specifying Bootstrap's `embed-responsive` class, etc.

This essentially means that the video, IFRAME, or whatever you put within the responsive container will respond to the size of the screen, i.e., as the window's dimensions decrease, so do the content's.  The actual height of what is in the container will be shorter as the screen gets smaller, probably a lot shorter than `700px`; how short, just depends on the aspect ratio.  You could enforce a `min-height`, specify `auto` or simply alter the design to flow more naturally, simply applying bottom/top margin as appropriate.

[Bootstrap: Responsive embed](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed)

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks so much! However, when I change 700px to auto, my video disappears.

Comment: This would have to do with the `position: absolute` in `.video-container` I believe.  If you change it back to `relative`, it should work.

Comment: Changing header-container's height to auto and video-container's position to relative does indeed solve this problem! However, now the text I would like to lay over the video appears under the video.

Comment: You could place your text in an element, probably within `.header-container` giving it, just as an example, the following: `position: absolute; width: 100%; text-align: center; top: 20%;`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

It may happen because you are already using the bootstrap class embed-responsive and again defining styles for the video tag. Try removing the styles for the video tag or just the min-height tag. That may be causing the problem

Comment: Or try putting the class embed-responsive-item by using iframe to load the video or putting embed-responsive-item in the video tag and remove css styles defined by you

Comment: Unfortunately, removing self-defined css styles does not solve my issue of too much extra spacing. Not sure about iframe but will look into it thanks!

Answer (score 1):

change the height in your `header-container` css class.

```
height: 700px;
```

change

```
height: auto;
```

Comment: The video disappears when I do this

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to use media queries to adjust the container .head-container size.

Try something like:

```css
@media (max-width: 1170px) {
    .header-container {
        height: 250px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the page or are you building locally?

Comment: I'm building locally right now. Would you be able to help if I posted a link?

Comment: Sure can if the link is accessible from my computer.

Comment: Here are my html, css, and js files. Thanks so much Justin! http://expirebox.com/download/3f78adafdf87f13a1f8441673b4b18cb.html

Comment: It looks like you need to insert this 

@media (max-width: 1171px) {
    .header-container {
        height: 300px;
    }
}

and then in your .header-container css, remove the min-height and just use height.

Comment: You'll want to create the correct media queries to fit the breaking points within your design also.